# Issues with One Hot Encoding for model with values not in training data

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I would like to use One Hot Encoding for my simple model. Yet it seems to trigger an error no matter how I set it up. First, One Hot Encoding is not converting string to float even though I have version 1.0.2 of sklearn. Now the issue is because the values in my training data are not the same length as in test data. Training only has 2 values, testing has all three. How do I fix that? The exact error is the truth value of a series is ambiguous. The error with this other idea is to reshape the data.

```
import lightgbm as lgbm 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X = [[ 'apple',5],['banana',1],['apple',6],['banana',2]]
X=pd.DataFrame(X).to_numpy()
test = [[ 'pineapple',0],['banana',1],['apple',7],['banana,2']]
y = [1,0,1,0]
y=pd.DataFrame(y).to_numpy()
    
labels = ['apples','bananas','pineapple']
ohc = OneHotEncoder(categories=labels)
pp = ColumnTransformer(
                        transformers=[('ohc', ohc, [0])]
                        ,remainder = 'passthrough')
model=lgbm.LGBMClassifier()
mymodel = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', pp),
                                ('model', model)
                                ])

params = {'model__learning_rate':[0.1]
          ,'model__n_estimators':[2]}
lgbm_gs=GridSearchCV(
    estimator = mymodel, param_grid=params, n_jobs = -1,
    cv=2, scoring='accuracy'
    ,verbose=-1)
lgbm_gs.fit(X,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue should be related to the fact that you're passing `categories` as a list rather than as a *list of array-like* (eg a list of list(s)) as the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) states. Therefore, the following adjustment should fix it.

```
import lightgbm as lgbm 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X = [['apple',5],['banana',1],['apple',6],['banana',2]]
X = pd.DataFrame(X).to_numpy()
test = [['pineapple',0],['banana',1],['apple',7],['banana',2]]
y = [1,0,1,0]
y = pd.DataFrame(y).to_numpy()
labels = [['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple']]   # observe you were also mispelling categories ('apples' --> 'apple'; 'bananas' --> 'banana')
ohc = OneHotEncoder(categories=labels)
pp = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('ohc', ohc, [0])], remainder='passthrough')
model=lgbm.LGBMClassifier()
mymodel = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', pp),
                            ('model', model)])

params = {'model__learning_rate':[0.1], 'model__n_estimators':[2]}
lgbm_gs=GridSearchCV(
    estimator = mymodel, param_grid=params, n_jobs = -1,
    cv=2, scoring='accuracy', verbose=-1)
lgbm_gs.fit(X, y.ravel())
```

As a further remark, observe what the [guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) suggests when dealing with cases where test data has categories that cannot be found in the training set.

> If there is a possibility that the training data might have missing categorical features, it can often be better to specify handle_unknown='ignore' instead of setting the categories manually as above. When handle_unknown='ignore' is specified and unknown categories are encountered during transform, no error will be raised but the resulting one-hot encoded columns for this feature will be all zeros (handle_unknown='ignore' is only supported for one-hot encoding):

Eventually, you can observe that the attribute `categories_` (which specifies the categories of each feature determined during fitting) is a list of array(s) (single array here as you're one-hot-encoding one column only), too. Example with `categories='auto'`:

```
ohc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
ohc.fit(X[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)).categories_
# Output: [array(['apple', 'banana'], dtype=object)]
```

Example with your custom `categories`:

```
ohc = OneHotEncoder(categories=labels)
ohc.fit(X[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)).categories_
# Output: [array(['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple'], dtype=object)]
```